# Dividing a matrix by a vector with ncol=number of matrix columns

Tags: r, matrix, scale

I have a dilemma in using R.

data1

```
    [A] [B] [C]
[a]  2   3   5
[b]  3   2   4
```

data2

```
[c]  4   3   5
```

result

```
    [A] [B] [C]
[a]  .5  1   1
[b] .75 .67 .8
```

here's the thing. I would like every values per column in data1 to be divided by corresponding value in data2, like divide column A by 4, column B by 3.
I would like to have a result with a structure identical to data1.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for `sweep`:

```
sweep(data1, 2, data2, FUN="/")

     [,1]      [,2] [,3]
[1,] 0.50 1.0000000  1.0
[2,] 0.75 0.6666667  0.8
```

Or:

```
t(t(data1)/c(data2))
```

Answer (score 1):

we could also do

```
data1/data2[col(data1)]
#        A         B   C
#[1,] 0.50 1.0000000 1.0
#[2,] 0.75 0.6666667 0.8
```